# Analysing Json file in Python using pandas

Tags: python, json, pandas

I have to analyse a lot of data doing my Bachelors project.
The data will be handed to me in .json files. My supervisor has told me that it should be fairly easy if I just use Pandas. 
Since I am all new to Python (I have decent experience with MatLab and C though) I am having a rough start. 
If someone would be so kind to explain me how to do this I would really appreciate it.

The files look like this:

```
{"columns":["id","timestamp","offset_freq","reprate_freq"],
"index":[0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7 ... 
"data":[[526144,1451900097533,20000000.495000001,250000093.9642499983],[...
```

need to import the data and analyse it (make some plots), but I'm not sure how to import data like this..

Ps. I have Python and the required packages installed.

Comment: I think you can create [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve), because your sample is very small. Maybe you can check [docs](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/io.html#io-json-reader) and function [`read_json`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.read_json.html)

Comment: It might be easier to use something like `JSONLab` to load the file into a MATLAB session.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You did not give the full format of JSON file, but if it looks like

```
{"columns":["id","timestamp","offset_freq","reprate_freq"],
"index":[0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9],
"data":[[39,69,50,51],[62,14,12,49],[17,99,65,79],[93,5,29,0],[89,37,42,47],[83,79,26,29],[88,17,2,7],[95,87,34,34],[40,54,18,68],[84,56,94,40]]}
```

then you can do (I made up random numbers)

```
df = pd.read_json(file_name_or_Python_string, orient='split')
print df
   id  timestamp  offset_freq  reprate_freq
0  39         69           50            51
1  62         14           12            49
2  17         99           65            79
3  93          5           29             0
4  89         37           42            47
5  83         79           26            29
6  88         17            2             7
7  95         87           34            34
8  40         54           18            68
9  84         56           94            40
```

Comment: Yes the file looks excatly like that! It is quite big though. The index goes up to 680204.

Comment: How would you plot two columns now then?

Comment: @Nillo, if you can provide sample data and tell us what kind of plots you want, maybe we can help. Basically, pandas dataframe has a `plot` method.

Comment: I found out that I could just use: plot("timestamp","reprate_freq") 
But thanks